# What does XMLdocument.load(url) Internal does to Load the XML from other Location

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to know what call `xmldocument` internally uses to load the XML, does it make `httpwebsrequest` or anything else.

I read about it here, but there is no enough info about the internals

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load.aspx

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

 doc.Load("http://someotherserver/test.xml");
```

Can anyone please tell me about this.

Comment: You can use .NET Reflector to see for yourself http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/

Comment: @i have to download this , its not allowed in my office laptop , can you tell me if you know theoritacally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the code that does it.

It's in the XmlDownloadManager class which is internal

```
private Stream GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    if (credentials != null)
    {
        request.Credentials = credentials;
    }
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    HttpWebRequest request2 = request as HttpWebRequest;
    if (request2 != null)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            if (this.connections == null)
            {
                this.connections = new Hashtable();
            }
            OpenedHost host = (OpenedHost) this.connections[request2.Address.Host];
            if (host == null)
            {
                host = new OpenedHost();
            }
            if (host.nonCachedConnectionsCount < (request2.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit - 1))
            {
                if (host.nonCachedConnectionsCount == 0)
                {
                    this.connections.Add(request2.Address.Host, host);
                }
                host.nonCachedConnectionsCount++;
                return new XmlRegisteredNonCachedStream(response.GetResponseStream(), this, request2.Address.Host);
            }
            return new XmlCachedStream(response.ResponseUri, response.GetResponseStream());
        }
    }
    return response.GetResponseStream();
}
```